# Quotes in html attributes getting marked up as &quot; in result from element.html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<div id="ma-uitemplates-container">
    <button id="ExecuteAbort" 
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-default" 
        data-mistro-command="Execute" 
        data-mistro-events='[{"SE":"click","MEM":[{"MEC":"NotificationManager","ME":"DismissNotification"}]}]'>
        Yes
    </button>
</div>
```

The attribute data-mistro-events contains some JSON data that I extract in code and parse into an object.

I am now writing some code that is saving some of the markup from a html page into a database as a template.

When I get this html using jquery:

```
$('#ma-uitemplates-container').html();
```

It gives the following result:

```
<button id="ExecuteAbort" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-mistro-command="Execute" data-mistro-events="[{&quot;SE&quot;:&quot;click&quot;,&quot;MEM&quot;:[{&quot;MEC&quot;:&quot;NotificationManager&quot;,&quot;ME&quot;:&quot;DismissNotification&quot;}]}]">
    Yes
</button>
```

You can see that jquery has converted single quotes I had on the attribute data-mistro-events='' to be double quotes data-mistro-events="", and then converted all the double quotes in the attribute value to ".

How can I get it to not do this, and instead, write the html as I have written it in the page?

Regards,

Scott

Comment: What about changing place of single and double quotes? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z79gdsok/)

Comment: JSON.parse won't accept sing quotes.  { 'property':'value' } won't parse into an object.  It has to be { "property":"value" }

Comment: You can replace `'` with `"` before parsing: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/z79gdsok/1/).

Answer (score -1):

Writing html tag attributes with single quote is invalid, this is why browser is converting you data-mistro-events attribute with double quote and your html is being breaking. You must use html attributes with double quote (") instead of single quote (') and write your json with single quote.

try following and this will work fine

```
<div id="ma-uitemplates-container">
  <button id="ExecuteAbort" 
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-default" 
    data-mistro-command="Execute" 
    data-mistro-events="[{'SE':'click','MEM':[{'MEC':'NotificationManager','ME':'DismissNotification'}]}]">
    Yes
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Cruiser, thanks for the response mate.  The issue here is if I do: JSON.parse("[{'SE':'click','MEM':[{'MEC':'NotificationManager','ME':'DismissNotification'}]}]");  I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.

Comment: JSON needs double quotes to be valid.

Comment: then you should convert your string to proper json by calling var properJson = JSON.stringify(eval('('+"[{'SE':'click','MEM':[{'MEC':'NotificationManager','ME':'DismissNotification'}]}]"+')')); and then var object = JSON.parse(properJson);

Comment: I converted the single quote json to object using eval function then converted that object back to proper json string, you your application can work properly with eval then you can use email for this string. other wise create a javascript block on server side and create an array based on your div id and required object

Comment: Cruiser, thanks again for the response.  The editor we use for expanding and minifying the JSON also does not accept single quotes in the JSON... this makes it more difficult to maintain the attributes.
http://jsoneditoronline.org/